# jquery pass post array to autocomplete source

Tags: jquery, arrays, autocomplete

I have following issue:
I try to create auto-complete with multiple input fields, without refreshing the page. First field contents street names. The second one should display available street numbers. My JS looks like this:

```
    $('input#strasse').on('blur', function() {
var hausnummer1 = $('input#strasse').val();
if ($.trim(strasse) != '') {
$.post('ajax/strasse.php', {hausnummer1: hausnummer1}, function(data) {
$('div#hausnummer1-data').text(data);
});
}
});
```

So, I got array on the main page as:

```
<div id="hausnummer1-data"></div>
```

Data are displayed correctly. Now, I wont to declare this array as source N°2 on the main page:

```
        $(function() {      
    var availableTags = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;//streets from query 
    var availableTags2 = ?; 
                    $("#strasse").autocomplete({
                        source: availableTags
                    });     
                    $("#hausnummer1").autocomplete({
                        source: availableTags2
                    });
});
```

Javascript is not my thing. I don't come further with this. I appreciate any help.

strasse.php

```
require '../connect.php';

$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT distinct(HAUSNRZAHL1) as HAUSNRZAHL1 FROM adresse.90101strasse where  STRASSENNAME = '" . mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['strasse'])) . "'");
$array2 = array();
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2)) {
$array2[] = $row2['HAUSNRZAHL1'];
}
echo json_encode($array2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming ajax/strasse.php return well done json, this should work :

```
$.post('ajax/strasse.php', {hausnummer1: hausnummer1}, function(data) {
     $("#hausnummer1").autocomplete({
          source: data
          //or maybe 
          source: $.parseJson(data)
     });
});
```

By the way, why do you write `$('div#hausnummer1-data')` and not just `$('#hausnummer1-data')` ?

Comment: still the same. I suppose, array is ok. this is what I get between div tags:["1","2","3","4","5","6","8","9","10","11","12","13"]. Another thing, as soon I add "var availableTags2=.... whatever" $("#strasse").autocomplete  is off. Seems like some variables don't get on with each other.should be so simple but its driving me crazy.

Comment: Maybe you should post your strasse.php code, or some real ouput from it. Also, did you try to do some console.log() with your variables ? like console.log(data), console.log(availableTags2), and so on ? These are really valuable informations.

Comment: I added strasse.php. Console log shows " Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined". hausnummer-data  is defined inside a function. in global.js.  as a post. Autocomplete function is on main page. I gess I have to pass variable from function to function?

Comment: And console.log(hausnummer1) ? if data is not defined, the input may be the cause...